# Is it possible for the Manager or Editor of a YouTube channel to do live video?

Tags: video, youtube

My institution has a YouTube channel and we were planning to do live lectures in it. So I added one of my colleague as the manager of the channel.

But he can't find the option to do a live video from the channel. Is it because only the owner can do it? Is there a way through which the Manager or Editor can do a live video?

Answer (score 3):

The only solution I found is to “opt out of” permissions from YouTube Studio, and handle the permissions in your Google Brand Account.
Add a person as Manager in Brand Account, and they will be able to “Go Live” from YouTube.
I just did this.

https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/34436067/channel-manager-unable-to-create-live-stream?hl=en&msgid=108266598
[image]

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me - only when permissions are managed in the Brand Account, it's possible to live stream.

Comment: this is pretty bad that you have to opt out. :(

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a Manager can definitely do Live videos. They're probably looking in the wrong place.

To set up or start a Live video on YouTube, go up to the top right and click on the Create button. There will be 2 options - Upload video and Go live

[image]

Then take it from there. It's as simple as that...

If you want any more YouTube advice, make sure to check out the very extensive library of videos at
http://www.youtube.com/c/DavidWalshOnline?sub_confirmation=1

Comment: Mine was a personal account first, and when I added managers to it they were not able to go live. But when I made that channel a branded one, the managers were able to go live.

Comment: As @LFS says I also was missing the option when accessing from the manager account. My solution was to make the other account an owner, there can be multiple owners added. This must be done in general channel settings not inside the youtube studio ones.

Comment: @eXPRESS but on a non-branded channel I could not see the option for setting me as an Owner... or perhaps I missed it, but I think on non-branded it is not possible to have multiple owners

Comment: @Tomeg yes you might be right, I'm not sure if my channel is branded or not, I find the Youtube experience quite confusing to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the branded channel had to go through the mobile phone verification by the owner (even though settings said the "Features that require phone verification" were already enbabled) and then start a live stream.  Then it says it takes 24 hours to set up the channel for live streaming.  I'm hoping after that period, the person with Manager role will be able to start a live stream.

Answer (score 0):

For me probably the reason was that the channel was not a brand account - as As @LFS above mentioned in some comment (actually that channel was not converted to branded account yet, so I cannot tell for sure, I am just guessing that it was the reason; but I think it is a good guess, because when I use the same actions for Manager account on other channel accounts that are branded, then everything)

**DETAILS**:

I was given Manager access to a YouTube channel (that channel was not a branded account but still the owner could invite me to be a Manager), but I did not have live streaming option (i.e. live button not available in YT Studio main page for that channel).

Also, when I crafted the URL manually (https://studio.youtube.com/channel/CHANNELID/livestreaming/manage) I couldn't do anything, but there was only a message "Only the channel owner can access live streaming".

It was true - the owner of the channel had a live streaming button on YT Studio, and could enter live streaming and do everything normally.